# Kotlin Data Binding - A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I converted a java data binding project into a kotlin data binding project. After compiling and trying to build facing the issue

> Unable to find the ActivityMainDataBindingImpl.

Tried multiple solution it was not working.

Enabled in gradle.properties:

android.databinding.enableV2=true

build.properties:

```
viewBinding {
    enabled = true
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'

Comment: Did you find anything about this error?

Answer (score 1):

Not much said in the question, so it is not possible to give a more accurate answer.

I do not know enough about gradle 3.6.3, but can say that
with  com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1

in build.gradle (module) it should be:

```
android {
   ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```